# How can I translate "select from this variable to this variable only" into a code?

Tags: php, string

I have three variables here.

```
$first= 'Start';
$second = 'End';
$testVar = 'Start here and here until the End more more more strings here';
```

How can i search *$testVar* if it contains Start and End strings, and i want to post Start up to the End string only.

Comment: Google for "regular expressions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is using substr() and strops()

```
substr($testVar,strpos($testVar,$first),strpos($testvar,$second)+3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous posts I'm assuming this is a PHP question. If so you can use:

```
list(,$result) = explode($first,$testVar);
list($result) = explode($second,$result);
```

[Codepad link](http://codepad.org/OHJQIxvq)

You can also use regex as:

```
$first = preg_quote($first);
$second = preg_quote($second);

if(preg_match("!$first(.*?)$second!",$testVar,$m)) {
        echo $m[1];                  
}
```

[Codepad link](http://www.ideone.com/R3mA6)

Comment: what if I'm going to search the two variable from a file then, post it from another file?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your comment. Do you mean the string to be searched in is content of a file? and you want to write the content between the start and end to a different file ?

Comment: What if `$first` appears more than once? You `explode` array will contain more than two items.

Answer (score 0):

I would also rather use strpos, strlen and substr:

```
$end_pos = strpos($testVar,$end)+strlen($end);
$result = substr($testVar, strpos($testVar,$start), $end_pos );
```